# explode string to php array with keys from another array;

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Is there a way to explode an a string into an assoc array with keys from another array?
example:
i have an array

```
$array = array('firstname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith');
```

now i have another piece of string like:

```
$fullname = 'Paul Phoenix';
```

so now i want to explode fullname into an array similar to $array with the same keys

```
$array2 = array('firstname' => 'paul', 'lastname' => 'phoenix');
```

Answer (score 2):

use like below

```
<?php
$a = array('firstname', 'lastname');

$fullname = 'Paul Phoenix';

$b = explode(" ",$fullname);

$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);

?>
```

hope this will sure work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_keys()` to get the keys from `$array`, explode `$fullname` on the space, and then use `array_combine()` to combine the two:

```
$array2 = array_combine(array_keys($array), explode(' ', $fullname));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullname = 'Paul Phoenix';

$name = array();
list($name['firstname'], $name['lastname']) = explode(' ', $fullname);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(7) "Phoenix"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(4) "Paul"
}
```

Update:

```
$array = array('firstname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith');
$fullname = 'Paul Phoenix';

$array2 = array_combine(array_keys($array), explode(' ', $fullname));
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(7) "Phoenix"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(4) "Paul"
}
```

Comment: you are hardcoding the keys of the array i need to take it from the 1st array itseld. if there is more keys in the 1st array there should be the exact same keys in the second array